# Getting pid of a particular instance of the application in unix

Tags: unix, pid

I have one application and multiple instances of the same application are running in the system. Every instance of the application is invoked with different argument.
I want to get the pid of a particular process which had been invoked with some argument i.e. pid of particular instance of the application according to the argument passed.
Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably check output of `ps -eo pid,args` and grep for the parameters I need and then cut the pid from the beginning of the output:

`ps -eo pid,args | grep --parameter=x | cut -c 1-5`

Check man page of grep. There are a lot of (somewhat confusing) options that will allow you shape the output of the command. In the above example `-e` selects all the processes to be shown and `-o` lets user to choose what to output.